# What sources of funds can be used for peer-to-peer Apple Pay?

Tags: messages, apple-pay

Peer-to-peer Apple Pay was announced during the 2017 WWDC keynote.

How does the money enter your Apple Pay account in the first place?

- Does it come from a linked credit card, as in how Apple Pay traditionally  works?  If so, would the transaction be considered a cash advance or a purchase by the credit card company?
- Does it come from a linked bank account or a linked debit card?  If so, does that mean giving Apple a pre-authorization to withdraw money from your bank account?  Also, is there an imposed or customizable limit to how much money can be withdrawn?
- Do you buy credits to be added to your Apple Pay account using gift cards, at a convenience store or at an Apple Store?

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Pay Cash is being introduced in the US first, with iOS 11.2 and watchOS 4.2 betas.](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/11/07/ios-11-2-public-beta-apple-pay-cash)  Both parties in a peer-to-peer transaction must have a suitable version of the software and have signed up for Apple Pay Cash.

Cash can be sent from a linked credit card (which incurs a 3% fee) or debit card.

Received cash is stored in an Apple Pay Cash card in Wallet.  It can be used for purchases or sent to a bank account.