# How can I add funds to Apple Pay Cash without a debit card?

Tags: messages, apple-pay

For example, can I add funds to Apple Pay Cash from my Apple ID funds? Or my credit card?

According to the only answer to [this related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286033/what-sources-of-funds-can-be-used-for-peer-to-peer-apple-pay), it *is* possible to add funds to Apple Pay Cash from a credit card, which incurs a 3% fee. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked post is almost 4 years old - a credit card  is not accepted currently. There is also currently no way to add money from your Apple balance or other external sources.

[Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207884):

> You can only add money from a supported United States debit card or prepaid card that's in Apple Pay.

Comment: So a credit card won't work – what about other methods? Can I add funds to Apple Pay Cash from my Apple ID funds, or PayPal, or anything besides a debit card?

Comment: @Lucca clarified this in my answer. What's the real issue you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification – I have now accepted your answer. The issue is simply that I'd like to try out Apple Cash for peer-to-peer transactions, but I don't have a debit card, only a credit card. It's a bit disappointing that, while I can use my credit card with PayPal, I cannot with Apple Cash. But whatever.

Comment: You could buy a prepaid debit card (must work with Apple Pay) using your credit card.